# php json decode returns array with lowercase field names

Tags: php, zend-framework2, json

I have a json string with following format

```
{"id":"38","orderId":"105","fileBackupDescription":"backup"}
```

after decoding the result array is of format

```
array
(
    [id] => 38
    [orderid] => 105
    [filebackupdescription] => backup
)
```

I am using it in a controller in zf2

```
$this->params = \Zend\Json\Json::decode($this->request->getContent(), \Zend\Json\Json::TYPE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: json_decode() function of PHP gives key name as it is.

Comment: Use `json_decode($this->request->getContent(), true)` instead

Comment: Solved It...!. I was using the decode code in preDispatch() function called from attachDefaultListeners(). Now moved the code to Action itself. Its working now...